# How to ensure that a logging Cmdlet is called for every exception in a PowerShell script module?

Tags: powershell, exception, logging, error-handling

In a PowerShell (5.1 and later) Script Module, I want to ensure that every Script and System exception which is thrown calls a logging Cmdlet (e.g. Write-Log). I know that I can wrap all code within the module Cmdlets into `try`/`catch` blocks, but my preferred solution would be to use `trap` for all exceptions thrown while executing Cmdlets of the Module

```
trap { Write-Log -Level Critical -ErrorRecord $_ }
```

Using the above statement works as intended if I add it to each Cmdlet inside the module, but I would like to only have one `trap` statement which catches all exceptions thrown by Cmdlets of the Module to not replicate code and also ensure that I do not miss the statement in any Cmdlet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is this.

- Set multiple `Try/Catch block` as needed.
- Group multiple cmdlet calls under the same block when you can. As you mentionned, we don't want to group everything under 1 giant `try/catch` block but still, related calls can go together.
- Design your in-module functions as Advanced functions, so you can make use of the common parameters, such as... `-ErrorAction`
- Set `$PSDefaultParameterValues =  @{'*:ErrorAction'='Stop'}` so all cmdlets that support `-ErrorAction` don't fall through the `try/catch` block.

(You could also manually set `-ErrorAction Stop` everywhere but since you want this as default, it make sense to do it that way. In any cases You don't want to touch `$ErrorActionPreference` as this has a global scope amd your users won't like you if you change defaults outside of the module scope.)

You can also redirect the error stream to a file so instead of showing up in the output, it is written to a file.

Here's a self contained example of this:

```
& {
    Write-Warning "hello"
    Write-Error "hello"
    Write-Output "hi"
} 2>> 'C:\Temp\redirection.log'
```

See : [About_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7) for more on this.

(Now I am wondering if you can redirect the stream to something else than a file

**Additional note**

External modules can help with logging too and might provide a more streamlined approach.
I am not familiar with any of them though.

I know [PSFramework](https://psframework.org/) have some interesting stuff regarding logging.
You can take a look and experiment to see if fit your needs.

Otherwise, you can do a research on PSGallery for logging modules
(this research is far from perfect but some candidates might be interesting)

`find-module *logging* | Select Name, Description, PublishedDate,Projecturi | Sort PublishedDate -Descending`